# delete data in cell after specific character

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in cells A1:A1000. It is a list of names followed by a small note, like this:

- sam" fast
- nick" long
- tom" quick

They all have `"` and a space after the names and then the note. What I am trying to do is delete the everything after the name.

I was playing around with macros to try and do this, but could not get anything to work. Any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a nifty trick without macros:

Select the proper range (or even just click on `A` to select the entire column) and then do `Ctrl+F`, click `Replace`, in `Find` write exactly `"*` and leave the `Replace with` box empty. Now click `Replace all` and tada !

It replaces everything after (and including) the quote with nothing because it uses `*` as a wildcard you left the replace box empty.

Edit: As suggested here is the VBA code for this:

```
Columns("A:A").Replace What:="""*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: +1 for quick and easy, without going through 'Text to Columns` ... might be worth showing OP how to write the `.Replace` method in VBA in case he needs it as part of a larger program.

Comment: Great answer.  Always make a backup of your data.

Answer (score 5):

**Easy!** I don't know what version of Excel you are using, but in short you want to do a `Convert Text to Columns` and then split the cells using a delimiter of `"`. This will leave you with two columns, one of the data you want and one you can just delete.

Here is the walk through in Office 2010:

1. Highlight column A
2. find the `Data` menu
3. find the `Convert Text to Columns` menu
4. Pick `Delimited` and hit `next`
5. In the `Other` box, type `"`
6. hit `Finish`

**Done!** Now you have all your names in column A and you can just delete column B.

To sum up, do a "Convert Text to Columns" and then split the cells using a delimiter of `"`. Super easy and fast.

Comment: also, when you get to the section that shows the data to be imported, select the second column, and change it to `Do not import column (skip)`, and you don't have to worry about deleting column B

Answer (score 4):

few options:

**Replace**

```
Range("A1:A1000").Replace """*", vbNullString
```

If you require to manipulate the value further then the below are more appropriate:

**With Regex:**

```
Dim str As String, strClean As String
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A1000")

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "\""(.*)"
        .Global = True
        cell = .Replace(cell, vbNullString)
    End With

Next cell
```

**Without Regex, splitting the string:**

```
Dim strSplit() As String
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A1000")

    If (cell.Value <> vbNullString) Then

        cell.Value = Split(cell.Value, """")(0)

    End If

Next cell
```

Comment: really? why all that looping and invoking `RegEx` when `Find` and `Replace` works so easily in this situation?

Comment: added Replace as another option, more efficient in this situation unless the user needs to do something with each value after processing.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to keep your source data, you can also do it with a simple Excel formula in the next column. Assuming that your data is in column A, the following formula will return only the name: `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("""",A1)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1()
    For Row = 1 To 1000
       S = Range("A" & Row).Cells.Value
       Pos = InStr(S, Chr(34))
       If Pos > 0 Then Range("A" & Row).Cells.Value = Left(S, Pos - 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: really? why all that looping when `Find` and `Replace` works so easily in this situation?

Comment: Scott, I agree that The other approaches are faster and easier. (I didn't know about the wildcards in Find that Alexandre posted, that one is going in my mental toolbox.) The OP was talking about macros, so I did it with macros. Might be useful to them if they run into something more complicated that they can't come up with a regular expression for.

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl + f`, click on `replace tab`, type `*` in the `find what` box and then click on `replace all`. No need to put anything in `replace` box. Here you are replacing everything after `.`.