# How do I remove certain text from a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a cell in Excel that contains the following:

**@dickfundy @ThatKevinSmith @aliciamalone @MovieMantz @dickfundy nope just Stranger Things Season 2 or Ready Player https:xxxxxxxxxxx**

I want to remove the usernames (everything starting with a "@") and I also want to remove the web-link (the "https:xxxxxxxxxxx"), and I want to end up with this in the cell:

**nope just Stranger Things Season 2 or Ready Player**

I have 60,000 other cells that contain similar text. How do I do this?

Comment: It looks like this question is related to another discussion on Stack Overflow available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957975/delete-data-in-cell-after-specific-character

Comment: what version of excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.16.4 (181110)

Comment: Do you have the `TEXTJOIN` function?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes but it doesn't apply here as all text is already in the same cell

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I believe your version of Excel has the `TEXTJOIN` function.  That being the case you can use this *array-formula*

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF((LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999)))="@")+(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999)),4)="http"),"",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999))))
```

where `seq_999` is a named formula that

```
refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))-1)*999)
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: I see now Ron, disregard my previous comment

Comment: @rsmalley74 If this is a one-off requirement, the function is OK.  If you will be doing this repeatedly on large data sets, a VBA macro will probably run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted up to the last user name (with Replace `*@` with nothing) then you might apply:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)),FIND("http",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))))
```

[image: SO53291434 example]

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work however it omits the first word that is leftover. So in the above example the word "nope" is omitted. Also, for other cells where only one word is leftover after applying this formula, the cell is then left blank.

Answer (score 1):

As a UDF:

```
Function FixIt(s As String) As String
    s = CleanUp(s, "@")
    s = CleanUp(s, "http")
    FixIt = Trim(s)
End Function

'remove all text segments beginning with LookFor, up to the next space
'  or until the end of the input string s
Function CleanUp(s As String, LookFor As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long, pos2 As Long, rv As String
    rv = s
    pos = InStr(1, rv, LookFor)
    Do While pos > 0
        pos2 = InStr(pos + 1, rv, " ")
        If pos2 = 0 Then pos2 = Len(rv)
        rv = Left(rv, pos - 1) & Right(rv, Len(rv) - pos2)
        pos = InStr(1, rv, LookFor)
    Loop
    CleanUp = rv
End Function
```

If you want something robust:

[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)